# Change opacity of header DIV using YUI

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Hey I have a div with "#header1" which I would like to keep at the top of the page as a user scrolls down. Now, I managed to get the div stick to the top upon scroll using "position:fixed" on "#header1" and what I would like to do now is change the opacity of the "#header1" once I scroll down and back to it's opaque state if i'm scrolled back up. I previously had posted my code but then learned we can use only YUI. Any advice would help. I am a total novice when it comes to YUI.

```
HTML:
<div id="header1">Hello</div> 

CSS:
#header1 {
     position: fixed;
     top:0px;
     z-index:1000;
     margin:0;
     padding:10px;
 }
JS:
var target = $('div#header1');
var targetHeight = target.height();


var scrollRange = maxScroll/(target.length-1);

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollY = $(window).scrollTop();
    var scrollPercent = (scrollRange - scrollY%scrollRange)/scrollRange;
    var divIndex = Math.floor(scrollY/scrollRange);

    target.has(':lt(' + divIndex + ')').css('opacity', 0);
    target.eq(divIndex).css('opacity', scrollPercent);
    target.has(':gt(' + divIndex + ')').css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Comment: can do the leg work and create a fiddler? :-)

Comment: You haven't declared the `containerHeight` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like the following:

```
var notScrolled = true;
var headerTop = $('header').height(); // header size
$(window).scroll(function () {        
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scrollTop > headerTop && notScrolled) {
        $('header').css('opacity',0.2);
        notScrolled = false;
    } else if (scrollTop < headerTop && !notScrolled){
        $('header').css('opacity',1);
        notScrolled = true;
    }
});
```

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/PB9G6/)